# How to solve transaction timeout due to heavy db call inside a loop - EJB

Tags: java, ejb

As described in the topic the total timeout is 120s, it exceeds when processing the transaction. Implementations is like below psuedocode.

Original idea is to take the methodA out of tx context using TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED and move the costly db method call to a REQUIRES_NEW (New transaction). But it's quite hectic considering the implmentation of method A. and the db proc is already optimized to a best of ability.

Is there any workaround for this :) Really appreciated

```
public String methodA(x){
 String resp;
    ------ other implementations
    
    if(x==10){
    
        for(int k; k < 10 ; k++){
            dbcall() --- method with heavy db proc which costs around 15seconds
        }
    }
    ------ other implementations

   return resp;
}
```

UPDATE : changing the timeout duration is not an option

Comment: If the `dbcall()` method is actually a fire-and-forget, meaning its return value and/or business logic is not required in `methodA()`, you can make it `@javax.ejb.Asynchronous`.

Answer (score 1):

> For Bean Managed Transactions, you can use the method
> setTransactionTimeout of the UserTransaction interface to set the
> timeout, for Container Managed Transactions, server specific
> configurations should be used (i.e. for JBOSS, you can use the
> annotation org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.TransactionTimeout).

Example:

```
    @TransactionTimeout(unit=TimeUnit.MINUTES, value=10)
    public void doAction() {
```

The doAction method transaction will be valid for maximum 10 minutes, the same can be handled with the following on bean managed transactions:

```
    public void doAction() {
        try {
            ut.setTransactionTimeout(60 * 10);
            ut.begin();
```

Note that the method takes the parameters as seconds (i.e. 10 minutes = 10 * 60).

[Resource](https://www.wideskills.com/ejb/transaction-timeouts#:%7E:text=21%20%2D%20Transaction%20Timeouts,-TOC&text=For%20Bean%20Managed%20Transactions%2C%20you,annotation.)

[Resource 2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13731/trxejb.htm#WLJTA252)

Comment: Im sorry I should have mentioned, increasing the timeout duration is not an option. Thanks btw :)

Comment: I mean there are three options that I see if increasing the transaction limit is not an option. 1) As you mentioned, move that method out of transaction with the assumption that if the transaction rollsback there won't be an issue on dependent data. 2) Look into how to make the db proc more performant 3) Look into how to batch your loop over the db proc and create different transactions per each batch. Again like #1 this depends if data in loop is not related in any way.

Comment: Does creating a new transaction for each loop iteration dbcall does  have an impact on the global transaction? l mean are the new transactions are inside the global transaction? Let's say for each new transaction in the loop takes 15s and for 10 iterations it would be 150s again and does that affects the global transaction if it aka methodA is not annotated as NOT_SUPPORTED

Comment: @Creek789 the batching idea would require the global transaction to not be there so yes, it would require the NOT_SUPPORTED attribute type. That’s why it’s similar to option 1 that you also mentioned